# Installing .exe applications in windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, installation

how to install software without admin password in windows 10, i have already tried some method like creating .bat file. but no use, will anybody know how to install the application without admin password

Comment: Ask your Administrator to install it for you.

Comment: mongoDB @ Biswa

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to contact your administrator and let him install it for you.

Think: If anyone can install software, which is based on Administrator privileges, without actual Administrator authorization, then the whole security system of Windows would be nothing. This is intentional to disallow normal users to install softwares (with exceptions but it's heavily dependent on the software itself).

Comment: i am already asked him but he is not responding, that's why i asked in this place, anyway thanks for the reply